# how to display data from database in another form label

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, instance

I'm trying to get data from database and put it in a label in a different form(student profile)

[image: http://s30.postimg.org/w5ruf5jkh/database_post_error.png]
(http://s30.postimg.org/w5ruf5jkh/database_post_error.png)

I have exposed the label from the student profile form:

```
public string Label9 {
            get
            {
                return this.label9.Text;
            }

            set 
            {
                this.label9.Text = value;            
            }
        }
```

but the problem is this:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Student_Profile.Label9.get'

so i have to create a new instance of an object or set it to static?
how would i do that?

Comment: Please show your code as a text.

Comment: Side note: your SQL is prone to SQL injection: use parameter(s) instead of hardcoding

Comment: @DmitryBychenko will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set it to the class (Student_Profile).

You need to set it to your object which begins with small "s" (**studentprofile**).